# Not able to open a page template

Tags: 2013-sp1, templating

It says

> Unable to retrieve item with id
>   Unable to open requested item
>   Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 and the Page Template name is 'Dynamic broker listing'.

Comment: Looks like it might be a dependency in the template itself? You get this error when opening in the CME? What type of template is it? VBScript? Have you tried loading the template through the API? Any additional error logged on the server?

Comment: You could also try opening it via WebDav

Answer (score 2):

I think your Page template has invalid xml data which is causing the issue

To troubleshoot and fix it, open the page template in template builder and run it against a page and fix the errors by removing the tbb which causes the invalid xml data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your valuable inputs. 
 Actually we had 2 issues with the page template-

1. sub_type was 7 for this template.
2. We also had layout code in compound template which was actually causing the issue of not letting us open it.